# Clarification of GLSL Function Calling Conventions

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gpgpu

I recently encountered some confusion while using a GLSL function which modified (and copied out) one of its input parameters. Let's suppose this is the function:

```
float v(inout uint idx) {
    return 3.14 * idx++;
}
```

Now let's use that function in a potentially ambiguous way:

```
uint idx = 0;
const vec4 values = vec4(v(idx), v(idx), v(idx), v(idx));
```

We might reasonably assume that after the call to the `vec4` constructor returns, our vector `values` should equal `{0.00, 3.14, 6.28, 9.42}` and `idx` should equal `4`. However, it occured to me to wonder if the order of evaluation of function arguments in GLSL is well defined, and if so whether the above assumed ordering is correct. Alternatively, could this result in (implementation dependent) undefined behavior?

So of course I consulted the [GLSL spec (v4.6, rev3, §6.1.1, p116, "Function Calling Conventions")](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf#page=122), which has the following to say:

> All arguments are evaluated at call time, exactly once, in order, from left to right.

So far so good. But then farther down the page:

> The order in which output parameters are copied back to the caller is undefined.

I'm not entirely clear on the significance of this second statement.

- Does it mean that for the function `float doWork(inout uint v1, inout uint v2) {...}` that the order in which `v1` and `v2` are copied back is undefined? This would matter if you did something like passing the same local variable in place of both parameters.
- Alternatively, does it instead mean that in the earlier example, the order in which the variable `idx` is updated is undefined, and as such the ordering of `values` is also undefined?
- Or perhaps both of these cases are undefined? That is, perhaps *all* copy-back operations on the entire line of code happen in an unordered manner?

It goes without saying that using multiple variables to hold the values prior to the `vec4` constructor call would trivially avoid this question entirely, but that's not the point. Rather, I'd like to know how this part of the standard was meant to be interpreted and whether or not my first example would result in `idx` containing an undefined value.

Comment: "*multiple variables to hold the values prior to the vec4 constructor call would trivially avoid this question entirely*" It's not merely that it would avoid the question. It's that it would be *more readable*, more easily digestible for the reader. Because as a long-time C++ programmer, my *immediate* reaction to this code is "undefined behavior". I was quite surprised that GLSL specified the order of evaluation as strict left-to-right. But even if GLSL makes it well-defined, the fact that many people will have to open up the specification to know that makes it a bad idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes of course, I agree. This is why I tried to clarify that I'm not asking about best practices but rather about the standard itself. I too was surprised to find that GLSL defines order of evaluation, but it bothered me that the standard seems to be worded in an ambiguous manner. I'm just wondering if I've missed something and perhaps it's not actually ambiguous? Unfortunately I can't simply go test it, as it could be undefined behavior.

Comment: You showed an example of bad practice but a reason for GLSL specification about evaluation order. I can not imagine a case when the order of copy back of output parameters matters. It would result in UB if the order of evaluation of input parameters was not specified.

Comment: @Ripi2 The provided example was meant as an MCVE with easy to reason about side effects and output. My inspiration for looking into the matter was a function `float rand(seed)` I wrote which incremented the seed value on each call for convenience. Note that at least Java has strongly defined ordering in this regard. The question seems to be giving the wrong impression as written, so I will edit it later today.